# Apparent movement in stationary GPS

Tags: python, gps

I have a U-blox M9N GPS module and I wrote a simple script to acquire raw data. I acquired some data while the module was stationary and I plotted the received coordinates. As you can see in the image below, an apparent movement can be observed (units in meters). Now, I understand the sources of error in GPS and I think that multipath was particularly relevant in this case (the module was placed near a building), but I don't understand why the samples seem to form a trajectory instead of being randomly distributed.

When acquiring data with the same module in the same conditions using U-blox software (u-center), this problem does not occur, even in absence of internet connection. Is there some post-processing technique that can be applied to prevent this phenomenon?

[image]

Acquisition script

```
import serial
import pynmea2
serial_com = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 38400)
while True:
    line = serial_com.readline().decode()
    if hasattr(msg, 'latitude'):
        lat = msg.latitude
    if hasattr(msg, 'longitude'):
        lon = msg.longitude
```

Comment: I can only offer personal experience -- I've seen this "wander" from other GPS devices, especially on startup as the device looks for GNSS messages. It works on increasing the accuracy of the position. How long after startup did you start plotting? Again, anecdotally I'd say this wander is just as normal as seeing a random distribution.

Answer (score 2):

If the GNSS calculated every position based only on the measurements it had taken over the last second (or 100 milliseconds for 10Hz positioning, etc) and therefore independent of previous positions, you would get a more random position distribution over time (not completely random). I'd still expect some time-dependent behaviour because the GNSS satellites are moving across the sky, and this also affects reflected (multipath) signals.

Nowadays, the GNSS receivers I work with (mainly Trimble and u-Blox) use a Kalman filter in the positioning engine so there is a dependence on previous states - every position is related to previous positions - and you see the tracks you have in your plot.

In my Trimble-centric world, GeoExplorer 2008 did not use Kalman filter, it gave positions which were quite random, it was replace by GeoExplorer 6000 which uses Kalman filter and shows the kind of tracks you see.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my next answer since the question appears to have changed.

I've done a lot wof work with u-blox (including M8-N) - they ALWAYS show the wander from your original question.  Unless you change the settings.

I suspect that a setting on the u-Blox module has changed between your original test and the test using u-blox software.  Have a look at the uBlox M8 Receiver Description / Protocol Spec (available on the u-Blox site), setting Dynamic Model to stationary (default is Portable) in the UBX-CFG-NAV5 message would give an image without any wander.  Alternatively, setting the Static Hold threshold (also in UBX-CFG-NAV5) to a non-zero velocity value will also keep your position stationary unless you move faster than the specified speed.

If you're on a Windows system, you can play with these settings using the u-Blox u-center application.